# Can you publish same app on Android Market with different .apks for different architectures?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I know that I can post a .apk for some "configurations" using the AndridManifest.xml entries for .

(I thought there was a similar entry for excluding specific devices but I can't find anything that suggests that now... just a ton of StackOverflow questions telling me you can't do that.)

Regardless, I'd like to post multiple apks for my app, where different apks satisfy different configurations (say, one apk for "largeScreen"s and one for "smallScreen"s).  I'd like the .apks to have the same visible-name in the market (different IDs or other things that are not customer-facing are fine).  I've seen forum posts that mention that you have to change the "name" but they don't say which name... I'd guess the "package" name (which isn't customer-facing) at the top of the manifest... but I'm not sure.  Is anything like this supported?  If not, does anyone have a feeling for the gotchas that I would need to look out for if I did publish the app under different visible-names for the different architectures?  Does it screw up metrics or payment or anything?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but not necessary in the slightest.  A well-made app will be able to cater to all possible devices with a single APK.  There are many tutorials on making an app seamless across platforms, I'd start by taking a look at android developers [best practices](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Some companies (those that make fruit ninja come to mind) have produced different versions of their application with different labels (such as HD or Tegra optimized).  The only reason I can think of that this is a good idea is that the underlying structure of the application is completely different from its counterpart.  For instance, one may delve into C code that is specific for Tegra-based architectures, while the same code would not work on other processors.  Normally this should be avoided, though.  One apk for all devices.

**Update**

If you are building a game, there is a very good session on designing an [Aggressively Compatible Android Game](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/building-aggressively-compatible-android-games.html) from the google io 2011 developer conference.

Comment: Thanks.  This comes very close to answering but I'd still like to know what information *needs* to be distinct for an app when posting to the market.  Its probably the package name in the manifest (the reverse-URL-thing) but I'm guessing.

Also, thanks for the link.  Its pretty common sense info but I have to play with the cards I am dealt....

Comment: The API version number acts as a filter for which applications show up in the market (it won't show up on phones whose API is below the one specified in the app's manifest), but as far as limiting it down after that, I'm sorry I don't know.